# python parse and print text before .(dot)

Tags: python

I am trying a program where it has to parse the text file:qwer.txt and print the value before '=' and after ',':

qwer.txt

```
john.xavier=s/o john
jane.victory=s/o ram
```

output:

```
 xavier
 victory
```

My program shows the entire line,please help on how to display specific text after . and =

```
with open("qwer.txt", 'r') as my_file:
     a = my_file.readlines()
     for line in a:
        for part in line.split():
             if "=" in part:
                print part.split(' ')[-1]
```

Please help! answers will be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you were actually splitting the string on a character in `for part in line.split()` (4th line in your example)

Comment: I expect you should probably have a `.split(".")` somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open("qwer.txt", 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        print line.split('=')[0].split('.')[1]
```

Comment: i get output but also error as : print line.split('=')[0].split('.')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Comment: @adarshram It might be because there might not be a '.' in the name mentioned.

Comment: OK, you can add if ('=' in line) and ('.' in line): to check the string is applied for expected condition.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to understand the [with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement better :-)

Here is my solution:

```
with open("qwer.txt", 'r') as my_file:
for line in my_file:
    name = line.split("=", 1)[0]
    print name.split(".")[-1]
```

The two lines can be combines like this as well:

```
print line.split("=", 1)[0].split(".")[-1]
```

The official doc of "with" statement is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Fun little way using regex rather than splitting, and will ignore bad lines rather than erroring (pretty slick if I do say so myself). Also gives you a nice list of names if you want to use them further rather than outputting.

```
import re

r = re.compile('.+?\.(.+)?\=.+')

with open("qwer.txt", 'r') as f:
    names = [r.match(x).group(1) for x in f.read().splitlines() if r.match(x)]

for name in names: print name
```